# Writing newline to file adds an unwanted space

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

In Java, i am creating a text File for a batch file to upload in other system.

When i am writing into that file at the end of line i am using `\n` to start the newline. While starting a new line its adding space into the file at the end of line.

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Try to use println instead of "\n".

Answer (score 1):

You aren't showing your code or describing the space. Possibly a CR character before the LF, depending upon what you are doing, platform and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the second line, print the newline character before each line and not after it.